# Passar paramento método GET pelo Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho a seguinte situação, quando testo se está passando o parâmetro com `var_dump`, não retorna.

O que estou tentando fazer é não carregar uma nova página mas que tudo aconteça nas divs.

HTML:

```
<td align="center"> 
    <?php echo '<a id="consulta" href="ver_imagem.phpid='.$aquivos['id_img'].'">Imagem '.$aquivos['id_img'].' </a>'; ?>
</td>
```

No *script* tento isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#consulta').click(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ver_imagem.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                $("#imagens_pn").empty();
                $("#imagens_pn").append(data);

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });             
</script>
```

Comment: Podes colocar a parte de PHP na pergunta também?

Comment: href="ver_imagem.phpid='.$aquivos['id_img'].'" não seria href="ver_imagem.php?id='.$aquivos['id_img'].'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer passar o href do link por jquery, se for isso mesmo segue abaixo o problema é o serialize:

```
<?php echo '<a id="consulta" href="id='.$aquivos['id_img'].'">Imagem '.$aquivos['id_img'].' </a>'; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#consulta').click(function(){

          var me = $(this);
          var dados = me.attr("href");

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ver_imagem.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                $("#imagens_pn").empty();
                $("#imagens_pn").append(data);

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });             
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado Solange, era o que precisa mesmo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ver_imagem.php",
            data: {
                nomeVariavelServer: $("#consulta").attr("href")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#imagens_pn").empty();
                $("#imagens_pn").append(data);

            }
        });
```

O nome da variável deve ser igual ao parametro esperado na api. 
API:

```
metodo(nomeVariavelServer)
{

}
```